# Empty statusText in Dropzone error callback

Tags: dropzone.js

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC app and using Dropzone 4.2.0 on the client side. My controller returns errors like this:

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(422, "The uploaded file is bogus.");
```

I've set up a handler for the [Dropzone "error" event](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-error):

```
init: function () {
    this.on("error", function (file, response, xhr) {
        // do stuff with xhr
    });
}
```

The handler is called when I expect, and `xhr.status` is what I expect, but `xhr.statusText` is always an empty string. **Am I wrong to expect that it should be populated?** Am I doing something wrong? If this is a bug, it seems unlikely that I'd be the first to notice.

I found an almost [identical issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2335) related to angular.js.  I don't think angular and Dropzone have anything in common, but maybe the underlying causes are similar.

Comment: Must be a problem with you ASP.NET version, I've tested with version 4.5 and above, same dropzone version, and `xhr.statusText` has the proper value.

Comment: @wallek876 Hmm.  We're using 4.6.

Comment: Then I don't know, 4.6 works fine for me. `xhr.statusText` contains the custom message "The uploaded file is bogus.".

Comment: Seen same behaviour with a tomcat default 404 error page - xhr.statusText is the empty string.